# I want to copy field value from Account object to Opportunity object

Tags: trigger, lightning, process-builder, custom-object, workflow

Copy from Account object [Field name: "Region") to Opportunity object (Field name "Business Region")

Both "region" field on account and "business region" field on opportunity contains same picklist values

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/388289/edit) your question to add what you have tried (it's OK if it fails) and how it is not working (e.g., *exact* error text). This site exists to *help*, not do the work. (From the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center: *"We’re not a place to exchange code or find implementation services."*) Please read more of the Help Center, and also take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do automation such as whenever Region on the account is selected, it should update on opportunity also, then -

> 1. you can create a after save flow on account which will update
>    Business region on child opportunities.
> 2. You can create a before flow on opportunity object so that whenever new opportunity is inserted, it will populate Business Region
>    from Account Region.

If you want to update all existing records in your org to populate Business Region based on Account Region, then you can do a data load.